# Error executing test cases for ngrx ComponentStore

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs, ngrx, ngrx-store

I am using ComponentStore and I have a method as below:

```
  readonly postFileToServer = this.effect((action$: Observable<{ file: File; preview: boolean }>) => {
    return action$.pipe(
      switchMap(action => {
        return this.schemaUploadService.postFiles(action.file, action.preview).pipe(
          tapResponse(
            event => {
              switch (event.type) {
                case HttpEventType.UploadProgress: {
                  const percentDone = event.total ? Math.round((100 * event.loaded) / event.total) : 0;
                  this.updateFileListProgress(percentDone);
                  break;
                }
                case HttpEventType.Response:
                  if (event.body) {
                    this.updateSchemaUploadServerResponse(event.body);
                  }
              }
            },
            (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
              this.handleError(error);
              this.updateSchemaUploadStatus(SchemaUploadStatus.READY_FOR_UPLOAD);
            },
          ),
        );
      }),
    );
  });
```

The above method is being called from the component as below:

```
uploadFileToServer(file: File, preview: boolean, withWarning?: boolean) {
    
    if(withWarning){
      this.schemaUploadStore.updateSchemaUploadStatus(SchemaUploadStatus.UPLOADING_WITH_WARNING);
    }else {
      this.schemaUploadStore.updateSchemaUploadStatus(SchemaUploadStatus.UPLOADING);
    }
    
    this.schemaUploadStore.postFileToServer({ file, preview });
  }
```

I am wring a test case for the component...but i want to mock the this.schemaUploadStore.postFileToServer

```
  it('should update schema upload status to UPLOADING when withWarning is false', () => {
    const file = new File([], 'testFile.xsd');
    const preview = true;
    const withWarning = true;
    jest.spyOn(schemaUploadStore, 'updateSchemaUploadStatus');
    component.uploadFileToServer(file, preview, withWarning);
    expect(schemaUploadStore.updateSchemaUploadStatus).toBeCalled();
  });
```

but getting error:

```
● SchemaUploadComponent › should update schema upload status to UPLOADING when withWarning is false

    expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalled()

    Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0
```

Need help to fix this. We are using Jest for unit testing.